# Self triggering is slow in OMNet++

Tags: omnet++

I am creating my own wired simulation model where nodes have layered architecture.

Application layer periodically generates packets then schedules itself using

```
scheduleAt(simTime() + 0.00000000625,AppModuleSelfTrigger);
```

This packet is then buffered in the next lower layer module. The lower layer module then periodically checks this buffer for packets. I'm achieving this by scheduling this layer module as well with

```
scheduleAt(simTime() + 0.00000000625,LowerLayerModuleSelfTrigger);
```

Similarly, every lower layers which uses buffers, I'm triggering them likewise to periodically trigger itself and check for any buffered packets to send.

This approach works fine. However, as I reduce the delay (*0.00000000625*) further then the GUI packet flow seams slow (e.g. After I see one packet flow event I have to wait very long period of time to see the next Packet flow in OMNeT++ GUI). But when I increase this delay value and rather use a higher decimal value, e.g. 0.2, then the GUI packet flows events seems to be fast (and I don't have to wait much to see the next packet in the GUI).

But the problem with setting this delay to higher values like 0.2 increases the packet latency (measured as `simTime() - PacketCreationTime`).

So, I am in doubt if I am using the whole process of self triggering correctly or I need to do some significant improvement.

Comment: Does the `Animation speed` affect the delay of showing next event? Do you test in "Run" or "Fast" mode?

Comment: No, events do gets generated as usual. Fast mode does not show gui effects so I am testing this with Run only. I this question I'm just asking if self scheduling like this is better or there are other means for achiving the same thing without using `scheduleAt()`. Also, is there a way to tell the simulation the tick duration and tick frequency ?

Comment: Self message is a universal way to schedule an action in the future. It may be used to model various actions. However, I thing that in your case `sendDelayed()` may be enough because you probably want only *send* this packet later. According to my knowledge there is no way to control GUI tick duration. There is only an option to control the precision of time representation in simulation (whole simulation, not only GUI) - look at option `simtime-scale` for ini file.

Comment: I agree with `sendDelayed()` option. What I meant was this, I have a simple module with buffers in it. The upper layer injects to this buffer. Now, I want this module to poll for this buffer regularly. How could I achieve this without using `scheduleAt()` self messages to trigger itself again and again ?

Answer (score 2):

Scheduling an event every 6.25e-9 seconds to poll for changes in the buffer seems like a sub-optimal way of structuring a simulation model. Assuming seven layers per host, you would waste over one **billion** events per second per host just to make sure that, indeed, the buffer is unmodified. Even though each event costs only a few CPU cycles to process, things are quickly adding up.

I would recommend writing your simulation models so that they take advantage of the fact that they **know** when the buffer changes. In the simulation model, there is no need to poll.

For example, assume we want to model a layer that takes 10 ms to process a packet and that polls its buffer state every 5 ms. Assume further that a frame arrives at an empty buffer at time t = 3 ms. At that time instant, we can immediately calculate that the frame will be noticed when the buffer is next polled (at t = 5 ms) and sent out 10 ms later (at t = 15 ms). Thus, all that is needed to model this process is to schedule a "frame sent" event at t = 15 ms. We never needed to poll.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. And this also explains why my model is taking too much time to see next packet transmission in the GUI. Please suggest how to create an App that generates traffics (without using such self message techniques)